# End of line error due to "use script"

Tags: macos, applescript

I have apple script which is working perfectly fine, until I add `use script “Alert Utilities”` at the start. Then it gives *Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.* error at `set md5 to do shell script "md5 -q " & quoted form of myFile` with `shell` highlighted.  What could possible be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `use scripting additions`and the code will run fine. Since AppleScript 2.3 (Mavericks) there is the new `use` statement. It will tell the neccessary resources that are required to run the script like which applications (optional), script libraries, cocoa frameworks in AppleScriptObjC or if it will use scripting additions or not. For backward compatibility when the `use` statement is not used, by default scripting addition are loaded. If the `use` statement is used, the scripting additions are by default not loaded.

So your script will look like:

```
use script “Alert Utilities”
use scripting additions
-- continue code
set md5 to do shell script "md5 -q " & quoted form of myFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `use "scripting additions"` statement. `use` statement automatically disables scripting addtions such as `display dialog`.

also,

```
set md5 to (do shell script "md5 -q " & quoted form of myFile with shell)
```

Comment: I added the `use "scripting additions”`, it gives the *Expected AppleScript, script, application, framework or scripting additions but found…* error (Don’t know how that would help). I had he `do shell script` in brackets but that gives *Expected “,” but found identifier.* error.

Comment: 1) the parentheses are not required 2) the command is wrong 3) don't use quotes in the `use scripting additions` statement (see my answer). So I'm even surprised that this answer is voted up.

Comment: I voted it up just now because I didn't even know about `use scripting additions` and once I added that to my script, my syntax error went away.